# Annotation for hibernate validator for a date at least 24 hours in the future

Tags: java, validation, date, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I know that exist annotation @Future.

If I annotate field with this annotation

```
@Future
private Date date;
```

date must be in future means after current moment.

Now I need to validate that date was at least 24 hours after current moment.
How can I make it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AfterTomorrow.java:

```
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = AfterTomorrowValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface AfterTomorrow {
    String message() default "{AfterTomorrow.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

AfterTomorrowValidator.java:

```
public class AfterTomorrowValidator 
             implements ConstraintValidator<AfterTomorrow, Date> {
    public final void initialize(final AfterTomorrow annotation) {}

    public final boolean isValid(final Date value,
                                 final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        c.setTime(value); 
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        return value.after(c.getTime());
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can add the default `AfterTomorrow.message` message in `ValidationMessages.properties`

Finally, annotate your field:

```
@AfterTomorrow
private Date date;
```

Comment: Can you advise where can I determine file name where I store validation messages

Comment: Assuming you're using hibernate validator, put them in `src/main/resources/ValidationMessages.properties`. Theoretically you can put the messages in another file, but I've never gotten this to work.