# Validation of a date with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, date, annotations

We have an existing hotel management system. I was asked to add a date validation in the "Create Accommodation" function in the system. The dialog looks like this:

[image]

The "End Date" is already validated as shown in the code below. The `@Future` annotation in Hibernate ensures that the date is in the future.

```
@NotNull
@Future
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date endDate;
```

**EDIT**

I was asked to add a validation to the "Start date". Only the present or a future date is allowed. I tried to use a `@Present` annotation, but I guess there is no such thing. Unfortunately, `@Future` does not accept today's date. I am new to this kind of thing. So I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: What class/framework does the annotation `@Future` come from?

Comment: it is hibernate i think

Comment: If the current date is the only valid value, why have the field at all?

Comment: Note that your form's format (`mm/dd/yyyy`) and annotation's format (`dd/MM/yyyy`) don't match.

Comment: @Axel import javax.validation.constraints.Future;

Comment: @DavidWallace sorry I edited my question Sir. It's for current & future date.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Hibernate**

You can use

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "create_date")
private Date startDate;
```

or on update

```
@UpdateTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "modify_date")
private Date startDate;
```

**Java (JPA)**

You can define a field `Date startDate;` and use

```
@PrePersist
protected void onCreateStartDate() {
startDate = new Date();
```

or on update

```
@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdateStartDate() {
startDate = new Date();
```

**Update and example**

After you have updated your question to not fix the start date to the present, you have to do a different approach. You need to write a custom validator to check if a date is now or in the future, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637732/annotation-for-hibernate-validator-for-a-date-at-least-24-hours-in-the-future).

Therefore you can introduce a new annotation in `PresentOrFuture.java`:

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PresentOrFutureValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface PresentOrFuture {
    String message() default "{PresentOrFuture.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Then you have to define the validator in `PresentOrFutureValidator.java`:

```
public class PresentOrFutureValidator
    implements ConstraintValidator<PresentOrFuture, Date> {

    public final void initialize(final PresentOrFuture annotation) {}

    public final boolean isValid(final Date value,
        final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        // Only use the date for comparison
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Date today = calendar.getTime();

        // Your date must be after today or today (== not before today)
        return !value.before(today) || value.after(today);

    }
}
```

Then you have to set:

```
@NotNull
@PresentOrFuture
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;
```

Well, that was exhausive. I have not tested it myself, since I do not have a set-up to do so now, but it should work. I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late response Sir. This are the codes for startDate: http://pastie.org/10958151 I hope you can guide me. Thank you.

Comment: If you can only allow the current timestamp, why do you have a setter method? Do you use Hibernate or JPA?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question Sir. It should accept current & future date. I use hibernate.

Comment: Thank you for your help Sir! :) I will try this and update you. :)

Comment: I tried your code Sir. I created a `PresentOrFuture.java` annotation and `PresentOrFutureValidator.java` class and added `@PresentOrFuture` but whenever I try to run the program I get this error: "The web application [/hms] registered the JDBC driver [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered."

Comment: Still getting the same error when I run it in the command prompt Sir. Here's what happens when I "mvn tomcat7:run" it: http://pastie.org/private/cyemsdl01qerwy2dfvnpjw

Comment: Do you have compile errors or warnings on this? I have changed the target annotation to `@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER })`, I do not think this is the problem, but you can try. Which Java version do you use?

Comment: I don't Sir. I tried it but I still get the same error Sir. Java 8.

Comment: Sadly, I do not have the environment to test it myself, but since you use Java 8, I probably have another solution for you. The error `ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file` can come from using Java 8 in old versions of Spring, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526695/java-1-8-asm-classreader-failed-to-parse-class-file-probably-due-to-a-new-java) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820068/asm-classreader-failed-to-parse-class-file-probably-due-to-a-new-java-class-fi). Now, compile your code with Java 7 or *at last* upgrade to Spring 4. Update me, Madame.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I was wrong the Java Version that I'm using is 1.6 and not 8. Other solution you suggest? Thank you for your patience Sir.

Comment: What Spring version do you use?

Comment: 3.2.8.RELEASE Sir.

Comment: As already stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526695/java-1-8-asm-classreader-failed-to-parse-class-file-probably-due-to-a-new-java) by **ItayK**, this may be a bug concerning ASM in Spring 3.2.8. The best you can do is upgrade to Spring 4.

Answer (score 7):

Now, in the updated new validator version i.e.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

via

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

we have @FutureOrPresent and many other helpful annotations that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is not make that field disabled(not editable) and populate with current date.. So you don't need a validation. 
 If you don't like this approach create an annotation of your own refer this url 
[Annotation for hibernate validator for a date at least 24 hours in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637732/annotation-for-hibernate-validator-for-a-date-at-least-24-hours-in-the-future)

Instead of 24 hour check, you need to check whether date value is equal to current date